# How to change order of pages when using \pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am preparing a beamer presentation and would like to generate 4 on 1 handouts using:

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}
```

The default order of pages in each slide looks like follows:

[image]

But I really want to have:

[image]

Is there an option to do this? or I will have to define my own layout? One could work on my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering\Huge\thepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\centering\Huge\thepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\centering\Huge\thepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\centering\Huge\thepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide an MWE which results in the second image, please? (maybe you change your title as the order is not "wrong" (speaking of the style in the region the `beamer` author comes from) but you want to change the default.)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Already did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own `\pgfpagesuselayout` which is in your desired order

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{4 on 1 new}
{
    \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperheight} 
    \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperwidth}
    \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
    \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
    {%
        logical pages=4,%
        physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
        physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth%
    }
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
    {%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}
    {%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
    {%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}
    {%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1 new}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \centering\Huge\thepage
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \centering\Huge\thepage
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \centering\Huge\thepage
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \centering\Huge\thepage
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. I was going to read through the manual, and now you saved me a lot of time. Thanks so much. Im just not familiar with pgf. I am an all-time pstricks user.